# PHP counter implementation

Tags: php, caching, counter

I'm using an API that limits the number of calls to 1000 per day. I wrote a PHP script that uses this API and I use it in multiple projects.

Now I want to include some function that counts how many times the API has been called each day from each project. I want to be able to just drop the script into a new project and have it work with minimal setup so I'd prefer not to use a database to store the number of calls.

I thought about maybe writing it to a file or storing it in a cache. What would be the best way to store this data that would work best in different environments? I know I could implement a check to see if the server allows file writing or if some cache extension is enabled. Is there a better way?

Comment: Might be a good use for the [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) module.  Most modern installations of PHP implement it.

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking.. check if APC is enabled if not try and write to a file.. just wondered if there were other options

Comment: So the API has rate limiting - does it not also have an endpoint to check the status of your limits? Re-check the docs, because it should have.

Comment: @Jimbo unfortunately it is a very limited API and does not provide that information that's why I need to store it myself.

Comment: Hasn't APC been deprecated in more PHP versions? At least the opcode caching... APC's `apc_store()` etc. were super-useful. I don't know if Zend Optimiser has any equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options I'd include in your implementations:

1. Ensure you are doing proper error handling, in the event you do exceed the number of calls. Does the API already track your current use for the day? If so, use that.
2. Set a constant defining the max calls per day you can make, divide that by the average number of calls you make per day, to calculate the frequency of your calls, if feasible.
3. Build your own custom interface where you define the storage methods you want to use, such as file, database, memory, file server, cloud storage, etc. Then toggle a flag to activate, and pass the needed parameters defining how to access that storage. Once the storage is defined, point your code that increments, compares and resets to your storage.
4. Lastly, and you probably already know this, think about the calls you make. Can you wait and perform a bulk operation to make better use of your daily limit? Do you even need to make the API call, etc.?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about calculating the frequency. That would mean I would need to store the history of each day's number of calls so I could calculate the average but it could be useful information.